# Django: Generic detail view IDView must be called with either an object pk or a slug

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to use detail view based on the values in the parameter.

URL:

```
url(r'^mousesmall/(?P<name>.*)/$', IDView.as_view()),
```

view:

```
class IDView(DetailView):
    model = RNA
    template_name = "home/details.html"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IDView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data = self.kwargs['name']
        context['object'] = RNA.objects.filter(rna_id=data)
        return context
```

I'm not exactly sure how to call the view with an object pk.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set [`slug_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_field) on your class based view so that it know which field you are considering as the slug (which I think in your case is `rna_id`. You will also need to set [`slug_url_kwarg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_url_kwarg) in your case as you are using `name` as your URLConf value

```
class IDView(DetailView):
    model = RNA
    template_name = "home/details.html"
    slug_field = 'rna_id'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'name'
```

You won't need to overwrite `get_context_object` now. You should also give your url a name:

```
url(r'^mousesmall/(?P<name>.*)/$', IDView.as_view(), name="rna_detailview"),
```

so it's easier to reverse in your template:

```
{% url 'rna_detailview' name=myobject.rna_id %}
```

Comment: You set slug_field twice in your solution. Also what is the purpose of reversing it in my template? Also, my rna_id is not the same as my primary key, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Reversing it just means getting the URL for that object. You do so by using the `url` template tag to look up the view that you've written. It is easier done when using a `name` attribute on your url. An alternative is to use the [`get_absolute_url`](If your `IDView` has a particular url, you can make it really easy to get access to that url by adding a [`get_absolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) method to your class. That was you can simply do `myobject.get_absolute_url` to generate a link to your page